# How to turn a dateFormatter value such as Jul 07, 2019 into Jul 7, 2019 from timestamp?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I made a convertDate class for functionality to convert my timestamps which are Date().sinceReferenceDate (i.e. since January 1, 2001 12:00am). I have one problem: when the date of the timestamp is over 3 weeks ago, I use the date format (Month, Day, Year (if earlier than current year)), but the issue is that if the day is not over 10, then the day looks like this: 01,02,03 (Jul 01, Jul 02), etc. while I need it to be 1,2,3 (Jul 1, Jul 2). I have been unable to find a solution, here's my code:

```
let nowTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
let finalTime = nowTime - mediaTimestamp //how long ago in seconds...

//For timestamp coverting below
print(mediaTimestamp, "<-- datfasfePass")
let timeToModify = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: mediaTimestamp)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"

//Below is for excluding the 2019 if the current year is 2019
let formatterForYear = DateFormatter()
formatterForYear.dateFormat = "yyyy"
let currentYear = "2019" //this is hardcoded right now
let finalYearDetermine = formatterForYear.string(from: timeToModify)
let currentFormatterYear = finalYearDetermine
print(currentFormatterYear, "<-- currentFormatterYear")

var finalDate = formatter.string(from: timeToModify)

if currentYear == finalYearDetermine {
    //then its currently 2019 whitch means we exclude the 2019
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
    finalDate = formatter.string(from: timeToModify)
} else {
    //do nothing to dateformtter
}

finalDateString = "\(finalDate)"
```

Comment: You should consider using the device locale to determine how you format dates rather than assuming that your preferred way is suitable for everyone.

Comment: @JoGoFo yes you are right... How would u recommend proceeding with that? (thx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you just need to use a single 'd' for the date e.g.:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"
```

However you should consider using the device locale to display your dates. DateFormatter does this automatically if you do not set a format or override the `locale` property:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
```

**EDIT:**
To drop the year component while still supporting the device locale you can use:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMd")
```

This will output "Jul 6" for a en_US locale but "6 Jul" for en_AU locale (for example).

Comment: so should I not assign a .dateFormat for the formatter?

Comment: how do I get rid of the 2019?

Comment: @dfgdfgdfgdfg see my update, should solve your problem.